# On a hasOne relationship, does the order of eager loading matter? - sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

Does the order matter in a hasOne relationship? Say, I have `Users` and each one has one `Cat`. I want to get all Cats greater than `3` years old.

```
const catsOlderThanThree  = await db.users.findAll({
    include: [
      { 
        model: db.cats,
        where: { age: {[Op.gt]: 3} },
        required: true,
       },
    ],
  });
```

vs.

```
const catsOlderThanThree  = await db.cats.findAll({
    where: { age: {[Op.gt]: 3} },
include: [
      { 
        model: db.users,
       },
    ],
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Both will return the same set of Cats and Users but the nesting of these entities will vary. If you set the `required` option in the first query to `false`, then the result will be different for both. In the first one, all users will be returned whether they have a cat older than 3 years or not. In the second one, only cats older than 3 years will be returned along with their users while other users will not be returned.

**Output of First:**

```
{
   catName: '',
   user: {
      userName: '',
   }
}
```

**Output of Second:**

```
{
   userName: '',
   cat: {
      catName: '',
   }
}
```